# Can one core of the Pi 4 run multiple hardware threads simultaneously?

Tags: pi-4, cpu

According to the [Raspberry Pi 4 Model B specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) the SoC used is [BCM2711](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/README.md). The BCM2711 uses an [ARM Cortex-A72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A72) core.  Does this have [**simultaneous multi-threading** (SMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading), like Intel cores with hyperthreading?  I have read somewhere that some newer ARM processors do.

Related: [software threads vs hardware threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5593328/1151724)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113696/discussion-on-question-by-thinwybk-how-many-threads-can-a-single-core-of-the-ras).

Comment: Why can't I vote to close this question which has no real relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @joan https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69092/212479  ...To be fair, it is a question about Pi hardware.

Answer (score 3):

I'm putting together a Raspberry Pi 4 cluster and had the same question (I need a particular minimum of hardware threads). Although there was no answer here, the question *was* answered in the comments, so for future visitors I'll summarize it:

The Raspberry Pi 4 does *not* have simultaneous multithreading ("SMT") hardware. Each of its four cores can only run one thread at a time. That said, each core will switch between (software) threads hundreds or thousands of times a second, so like any Intel- or AMD-based system it can still handle many threads "at once," from a human perspective.

Comment: Right. The credits should go to @goldilocks cause he pointed at this topic during discussion. If goldilocks writes an answer I'd accept it. If not I'll accept this one that we can close this question.

Comment: You should improve "...run one thread at a time..." probabably cause it could be misinterpreted as software thread.

Comment: @thinwybk, I'll be happy to edit it, but I'm not sure what wording would improve it. Each core can run one thread at a time, regardless of what kind of thread it might be.

Comment: Just have a look into the discussion hyperlinked in the comment section of the question. It's pretty obvious then.